# Calculate the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to calculate the sum for $x\in(-1,1)$ of this:  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}$$
So far I managed that 
$$\int \frac{x^n}{n}dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}, $$
and
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}=-\log(1-x), $$
and
$$ \int -\log(1-x) dx \overset{c}{=} x+(1-x)\log(1-x). $$
But I really don't know if I can put it somehow together or not.

Comment: Wolfram agrees with the [result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+x%5E(n%2B1)%2F(n(n%2B1)))

Comment: It's the correct result. You  just have to check the series and your answer have the same value if $x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f (x ) $ be your sum.

then

$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac {x^n}{n} $$
and
$$f''(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}x^n=\frac {1}{1-x} $$
thus
$$f'(x)=-\ln (1-x) $$
and
$$f (x)=x+(1-x)\ln (1-x) $$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your answer is correct.

You can also see this by writing $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: Very nice, easy and elegant solution, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Using partial fraction decomposition $$\frac 1{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$ So
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}n-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}n-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=x \log(1-x)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$ Now, $$\frac d{dx} \left(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)=x^n\implies \frac d{dx} \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \right) =\frac{x}{1-x}=\frac{x-1+1}{1-x}=\frac{1}{1-x}-1$$ Now, integrate to get $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=-\log(1-x)-x$$

Comment: I would personally do this:
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left (\frac{x^{n}}{n} \right )-x = -\log(1-x)-x$

Comment: @JuanCarlos. There are so many ways to do it ! I probably took a too long one. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may write, for $|x|<1$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)}=x+(1-x)\ln(1-x)
$$ using
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{x^m}{m}-\frac{x^1}{1}=-\ln(1-x)-x.
$$

Answer (score 1):

When $|x| < 1$:

$$\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n(n+1)} &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n} - \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \\ &= x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^n}{n} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \\ &= x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^n}{n} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^n}{n} + x \\ & =  -x\ln(x-1) + \ln(x-1) + x\\ &= x+(1-x)\ln (1-x)\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $S(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}$, then on $x\in(-1,1)$, 
$$S''(x)=\left[\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}\right]''
=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{x^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}\right]''
=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{x^{n-1}}=\frac1{1-x},$$
hence,
$$S(x)=\int\int\frac1{1-x}dxdx=-\int[\ln(1-x)+C_1]dx=x\ln(1-x)+(C_1-1)x-\ln(1-x)+C_2.$$
Let $x=0$ in the definition of $S(x)$, we can obtain $S(0)=0$ and $S'(0)=0$, then we know $C_1=C_2=0$, so
$$S(x)=x\ln(1-x)-x-\ln(1-x).$$